# Tal condition, defining multiple conditions within same line

Tags: php, phptal, template-tal

Is there an alternative to what I do below :

```
...
<div class="abc" tal:condition="this/condition1">
    <div class="abc2" tal:condition="this/condition2">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Such as :

```
...
<div class="abc" tal:condition="this/condition1 AND this/condition2">
...
</div>
...
```

Comment: I take it there is no way or is the question not clear ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit silly, but there's no logical AND in TALES.

You can use `php:` prefix:

```
<div tal:condition="php:this.condition1 AND this['condition2']">
```

but keep in mind that with `php:` you need to use type-dependent syntax (`.` for objects, `[]` for arrays, because `/` becomes division).